# Importing a text file gives error

Tags: python, string, file-io, floating-point, readlines

I have a text file that has the following data:

```
5298    10036   4   360 8
6128    11947   2   385 7
9472    18930   0   233 4
5056    9790    1   293 6
```

I read this file using the following code:

```
file1 = open("test.txt","r")
lines = file1.readlines()       
BF=[map(float, line.split()) for line in lines]
```

This gives me the following error:

```
could not convert string to float: ÿþ5
```

Why do I see this error?

Update:

```
print lines
```

shows:

```
['\xff\xfe5\x002\x009\x008\x00\t\x001\x000\x000\x003\x006\x00\t\x004\x00\t\x003\x006\x000\x00\t\x008\x00\r\x00\n', '\x006\x001\x002\x008\x00\t\x001\x001\x009\x004\x007\x00\t\x002\x00\t\x003\x008\x005\x00\t\x007\x00\r\x00\n', '\x009\x004\x007\x002\x00\t\x001\x008\x009\x003\x000\x00\t\x000\x00\t\x002\x003\x003\x00\t\x004\x00\r\x00\n', '\x005\x000\x005\x006\x00\t\x009\x007\x009\x000\x00\t\x001\x00\t\x002\x009\x003\x00\t\x006\x00\r\x00\n', '\x001\x005\x000\x006\x004\x00\t\x003\x000\x001\x006\x000\x00\t\x001\x00\t\x003\x001\x002\x00\t\x008\x00']
```

Comment: I think you have utf-8 BOM, try `file1 = open("test.txt","r", "utf-8")`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error with that file content. Are you sure you dont have any other non numeric character in your file?

Comment: You see that because you have the text `ÿþ5` somewhere in the file and it can't be parsed to a float. You should change the aggregation to a loop and handle such cases with `try`/`except`.

Comment: Actually I think it's utf-16 try `file1 = open("test.txt","r", "utf-16")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a [utf-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) BOM, this is `0xFE` `0xFF` which is interpreted as `ÿþ`, you need to open the file and pass the encoding.

```
file1 = open("test.txt","r", encoding = "utf-16")
```

As you using python 2 you could try this:

```
import io
file1 = io.open("test.txt","r", encoding = "utf-16")
```

Comment: Hi, this gives me the following error: TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Try this: `file1 = open("test.txt","r", "utf-16")`

Comment: What version python are you using?

Comment: Try `import io file1 = io.open("test.txt","r", encoding = "utf-16")`

Comment: Pyhton version: 2.7.6 | 32-bit
Tried io: reads the file but when I print the "lines", I get the following: [u'5298\t10036\t4\t360\t8\n',
 u'6128\t11947\t2\t385\t7\n',
 u'9472\t18930\t0\t233\t4\n',
 u'5056\t9790\t1\t293\t6\n',
 u'15064\t30160\t1\t312\t8']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73657/discussion-between-abhinav-kumar-and-edchum).

Comment: Late to the game, but this is the perfect answer I needed!  Was messing around with type conversions for ~30 minutes before stumbling across this.

Answer (score 1):

```
import io
file1 = io.open("test.txt","r",encoding='utf-16')
lines = file1.readlines()
BF=[map(float, line.split()) for line in lines]
print BF
```

Result:

```
[[5298.0, 10036.0, 4.0, 360.0, 8.0], [6128.0, 11947.0, 2.0, 385.0, 7.0], [9472.0, 18930.0, 0.0, 233.0, 4.0], [5056.0, 9790.0, 1.0, 293.0, 6.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be a possibility that there is a line break included at the end if each line, why dont you print line.split() for each line in lines; just to confirm if the numbers split correctly or not....